# Как использовать ресурсы удаленного компьютера (Jetson Nano)?

Tags: python, сервер, opencv, openvpn, gpu

Я сделал программный код для CSI-камеры и надо запустить его на удаленном компьютере. На удаленный Jetson Nano установили сервер и я подключился к нему по OpenVPN, но что делать дальше не знаю. Кто знает как решить проблему, пж отзовитесь. P.s. Программа написана на Python OpenCV.

Comment: ну запускай там свой скрипт в чем проблема? ssh-доступ есть?

Comment: @Yakov я просто не сильно разбираюсь в серверах и доступах так что я не очень понимаю как понять что скрипт использует ресурсы удаленного компьютера. То есть мне просто подключиться и запустить программу как обычно? Просто я не совсем понимаю слова "запускай там" ведь когда я подключаюсь к серверу у меня не появляется никакого окна или папки (или интерфейса для "того" компа). И я работаю в виндовс так что не знаю как проверить ssh.

Comment: в виндовс(10) ссш-клиент тоже есть. он доступен в пауэршелле, ssh стандартный способ подключения к удаленным nix-системам. ты подключаешься к впн-серверу, получаешь какой-то адрес, у сервера твоего джетсона тоже есть какойто адрес, который доступен через впн-подключение, ты открываешь powershell/cmd или качаешь putty и указываешь строку вида ssh user@server_ip. вводишь пароль получаешь терминал на удаленном пк. копируешь туда свой скрипт хоть через буффер обмена, хоть через scp/WinSCP даешь скрипту право на исполнение chmod +x твой_скрипт.py запускаешь ./твой_скрипт.py смотришь.

Comment: Если у тебя IDE PyCharm там есть возможность настроить запуск скриптов из IDE на удаленном ПК по ssh.

Comment: @Yakov да у меня PyCharm. Буду пробовать вашу инструкцию. Спасибо!

Comment: p.s. сначала обязательно подключитесь к хосту через командную строку, т.к. pycharm не задает вопрос на принятие отпечатка (по крайней мере 2019я версия так себя вела), надо сначала подключиться с хоста.